# What is advantages of using iptables-restore over normal script file?

Tags: iptables

I was trying to compare iptables-restore and restore all iptables rule through a normal script file. What are the advantages/disadvantages of iptables-restore because I can reload all my iptables rule by simply storing them into a shell script and running that. I request all to comment their view on this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost a opinion based question, so there comes mine:

You should use your scripts to create/remove/modify rules, and then, `service iptables save`, or `iptables-save` to make them persistent across server or ervice restarts. Then, at restart of for reverting changes, use `service iptables restore` / `iptables-restore`

Doing things like that, from a standard way, you will allow any user or app with permissions in /etc/sudoers adding their rules. If you put all your rules in a shell script, you will have to deal with all rules of all services. Maybe it's that you want, but is more work for you.

Comment: Thanks Raul for your view. I would like to add one more thing to your reply. You said, we should use scripts to create/remove/modify rule. I just tried we can even modify or remove rules in the file which is created by iptables-save command. That file is also very much readable. So, isn't it better to use iptables-save only and not the scripts?

Comment: **"That file is also very much readable"** for a human. `iptables-save` command format is a good *user interface*, and it's easy for you to manage rules in `nat` or `filter` tables. But it's not as easy for automating rules insertions or deletions, that perform better through `iptables` command  direct invocations

Comment: I would like to compare these two methods in term of speed and overhead. iptables-restore is faster but has more number of system calls where as scripting is slower but has less number of system calls. Now I'm confused what should I conclude as best approach for restoring all rules :( .